# How do I generate PNS handle which needs to be used for third party tools or SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-notifications, azure-notificationhub

**Step 1**: Doing mobile registration by getting the FCM Token from Google Firebase.

**Step 2**: Call Azure Notification Hub through SDK for the mobile registration input as above FCM token with a specific tag.

**Step 3**: After Successful registration. Pushing a notification. The notification is being pushed successfully.

**Step 4**: This pushed notification message is not receiving on mobile device and also not syncing to the firebase Cloud Messaging interface.

Comment: Questions asking for help how to get started with a solution is not what Stackoverflow is for. Please see What Questions Are On-Topic and which ones Are not On-Topic - It is expected for you to do your own research, decide on a solution and implement it. If you have issues with an implementation post your code please in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can help you out.

Comment: Doing Registration by getting FCM Token from Firebase
{string tag = "ict";userTag.Add(tag);
GcmRegistrationDescription registration = new GcmRegistrationDescription(handle, userTag);
registration.RegistrationId = registrationId;
registration = await hub.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(handle, userTag);
var notify =     "{ \"data\" : {\"message\"Device has been registed successfully\"}}";
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationOutcome outcome = await Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notify, userTag);}

Comment: Message is being sent properly from API but this message is not delivering on mobile device as well as not syncing to the Firebase cloud Messaging.

Comment: I tried to send the message through PushTry.com using same firebase token but message is not delivering to mobile device and Firebase Cloud Messaging interface.

Comment: If you send a message directly from the Firebase console do you get the message on the device?